# Why the sequence of the circle is not correct?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I was expected the circle to be 1,2,3 and 4 but the output is 4,1,2 and 3. I don know whether is the `position: absolute;` that cause it happen. Kindly to receive any feedback.

```
<template>
  <q-page class="column flex-center">
    <q-card class="my-card">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Our Changing Planet</div>
        <div class="text-subtitle2">by John Doe</div>
      </q-card-section>

      <div
        v-for="index in 4"
        :key="index"
        class="circle"
        :style="`background-color: ${[index]}`"
      >
        {{ index }}
      </div>
    </q-card>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup></script>
<style lang="scss">
.my-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: $positive;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  top: 40px;
  background-color: $negative;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-bybqfg?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.circle:nth-child(n)` selects an element satisfying the following conditions:

- has class `circle`
- is the n-th child of its parent.

Your DOM looks like this:

- `.q-card__section` // :nth-child(1)
- `.circle`: content 1 // :nth-child(2)
- `.circle`: content 2 // :nth-child(3)
- `.circle`: content 3 // :nth-child(4)
- `.circle`: content 4 // :nth-child(5)

You'll likely get the [expected result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-o9bcgv?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue) by wrapping `.circle`s in a separate container:

- `.q-card__section` // :nth-child(1)
- `div` // :nth-child(2)

  - `.circle`: content 1 // :nth-child(1)
  - `.circle`: content 2 // :nth-child(2)
  - `.circle`: content 3 // :nth-child(3)
  - `.circle`: content 4 // :nth-child(4)